# positioning a button programmatically with unexpected result

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to position a button at a fixed position inside a UIImageView (AspectFit) which itself is inside a UIScrollView. This worked perfectly on my first try when the UIScrollView and the UIImageView containers both covered the whole screen, the button was pinned to a certain location of the image and stayed at position during zooming. You can see the result in the below image.

[image]

As you can obviously see there are white borders above and below the image (related to aspect fit) therefore I had to do some calculation to get the margin from top to calculate the "real" y position of the red square. My code looks like this:

```
let originalImageSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height)
let aspectRatio = image.size.width/image.size.height;
let requiredHeight = self.view.bounds.size.width / aspectRatio;
let screenHeight = self.view.bounds.height;
let marginTop = (screenHeight - requiredHeight) / 2;


let renderedImageSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: self.view.bounds.width, height: requiredHeight)

let x:Double = 0
let y:Double = 0

let button = UIButton()
button.frame = CGRect(x: Double(renderedImageSize.width/originalImageSize.width) * x,
y: Double(renderedImageSize.height/originalImageSize.height) * y + Double(marginTop),
width: 10, height: 10)
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
imageView.addSubview(button)
```

As you see I calculated the "marginTop" to get the real y position. The square is perfectly located on x: 0 and y:0 (relative to the image). So far so good, this example worked perfectly.

Now I created a new view which contains a navigation bar and tab bar. The scrollView is in between and no longer covers the whole screen but only the area between my navigation and my tab bar. The imageView has the same size like my scrollView. Pretty much the same as in the example above. Now I tried to set my button a specific location again, but this time there is an offset on the y axis of exactly 6 pixels and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. And to make it even worse when testing it on other devices the offset on the y axis is even bigger than 6 pixels, while the first example works perfectly accross all devices I tested. You can see the result with the "wrong" y-axis value here.

[image]

I changed my code to the following, based on the fact that sizes should be calculated according to the "new" scrollView size.

```
let originalImageSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height)
let aspectRatio = image.size.width/image.size.height;
let requiredHeight = scrollView.bounds.size.width / aspectRatio;
let screenHeight = scrollView.bounds.height;
let marginTop = (screenHeight - requiredHeight) / 2;


let renderedImageSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: scrollView.bounds.width, height: requiredHeight)

let x:Double = 0
let y:Double = 0

let button = UIButton()
button.frame = CGRect(x: Double(renderedImageSize.width/originalImageSize.width) * x,
                      y: Double(renderedImageSize.height/originalImageSize.height) * y + Double(marginTop),
                      width: 10, height: 10)
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
imageView.addSubview(button)
```

A quick workaround would be something likes this, but it is hacky as hell and doesn't work for other device sizes and I obviously want to learn how to do it the right way:

```
[...] y: Double(renderedImageSize.height/originalImageSize.height) * y + Double(marginTop) - 6, [...]
```

I've been sitting on this for hours now and still don't have any idea why the y-axis is off even though the calculation of the top margin should be right and why the y axis offset is even bigger now on different devices. I'm thankful for any advice as I'm pretty new to iOS developing and I guess I'm missunderstanding something related to calculating correct sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, that the solution to my problem is rather simple. I first started wondering when I saw that `scrollView.bounds.size.height`
returned a bigger value than the actual screen height on devices smaller than the iPhone X, which seemed pretty strange. Then I tried to figure out how to find the "real" size of my scrollView on different devices, because it is obviously not *really* bigger than the whole screen according to the simulator visual result.

So instead of doing the above quoted calculation inside `viewDidLoad()` doing all my calculation in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` instead and this solved the whole problem.

The only thing I'm still wondering about is, why there was an offset even on the iPhone X as it was my default template in Xcode.